# DAX/M count for consecutive months for every ID in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I need help finding a way to count the number of consecutive months:

- For every "ID" (Text Column)
- Having the column "Status" either "Missing" or "On hold"

Here is what my table looks like (the last two columns are the output I would like to see):

| ID | Year | Month | Date (01-Month-Year) | Status | *Consecutive Months "Missing"* | *Consecutive Months "On Hold"* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID40 | 2019 | 6 | 01/06/2019 | Missing | 0 | - |
| ID40 | 2019 | 7 | 01/07/2019 | Missing | 2 | - |
| ID40 | 2019 | 8 | 01/08/2019 | Missing | 3 | - |
| ID40 | 2019 | 11 | 01/11/2019 | Missing | 0 | - |
| ID40 | 2019 | 12 | 01/12/2019 | Missing | 2 | - |
| ID40 | 2020 | 9 | 01/09/2020 | Missing | 0 | - |
| ID499 | 2019 | 1 | 01/01/2019 | On Hold | - | 0 |
| ID499 | 2019 | 2 | 01/02/2019 | On Hold | - | 2 |
| ID499 | 2019 | 3 | 01/03/2019 | On Hold | - | 3 |
| ID499 | 2020 | 9 | 01/09/2020 | On Hold | - | 0 |
| ID499 | 2020 | 10 | 01/10/2020 | On Hold | - | 2 |
| ID499 | 2020 | 8 | 01/08/2020 | Missing | 0 | - |
| ID499 | 2020 | 9 | 01/09/2020 | Missing | 2 | - |
| ID499 | 2020 | 10 | 01/10/2020 | Missing | 3 | - |
| ID499 | 2020 | 11 | 01/11/2020 | Missing | 4 | - |
| ID499 | 2020 | 12 | 01/12/2020 | Missing | 5 | - |

Is there any way to do this besides with merged nested queries in "M"? Unfortunately I have already tried this, but PowerBI has trouble processing the data.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Is there any column you can order data with?

Comment: No, I don't think so. At the moment data is ordered first by Date and then by ID (95690 unique IDs).

Comment: Data can be both Missing and OnHold at the same time, like for ID 499 for Month 10 Year 2020?

Comment: You're right, my dummy data is not entirely correct; as you point out, for the same ID and in a given month, it is either Missing OR On Hold.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to build a table of the Years and Months since the first Year in the table and remove from it the Year Months that appear in the table. Than compute the difference in months between the current Year Month and the last non existent Year Month.

This is a possible calculated column that uses the EXCEPT function to build the table with the missing Year Months. To ease the computation of the difference in months across the years, it also prepares a YearMonthNumber value with the progressive month number from the first year month

Since in the example table there are separate columns for the Status, I added an IF to split the columns accordingly

I also added a check to return 0 instead of 1, to match the example data

```
Consecutive Months Missing = 
IF (
    T[Status] = "Missing",
    VAR FirstYear =
        MIN ( T[Year] )
    VAR CurrentYear = T[Year]
    VAR CurrentMonth = T[Month]
    VAR CurrentYearMonthNumber = ( CurrentYear - FirstYear ) * 12 + CurrentMonth
    VAR YearMonths =
        GENERATE (
            SELECTCOLUMNS ( GENERATESERIES ( FirstYear, CurrentYear ), "Year", [Value] ),
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, 12, 1 ),
                "Month", [Value],
                "YearMonthNumber",
                     ( [Year] - FirstYear ) * 12 + [Value]
            )
        )
    VAR CurrentIDAndStatusYearMonths =
        CALCULATETABLE (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                SUMMARIZE ( T, T[Year], T[Month] ),
                "YearMonthNumber",
                     ( T[Year] - FirstYear ) * 12 + T[Month]
            ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( T, T[ID], T[Status] )
        )
    VAR MissingYearMonths =
        EXCEPT ( YearMonths, CurrentIDAndStatusYearMonths )
    VAR FirstMissingYearMonthNumber =
        MAXX (
            FILTER ( MissingYearMonths, [YearMonthNumber] < CurrentYearMonthNumber ),
            [YearMonthNumber]
        )
    VAR Result = CurrentYearMonthNumber - FirstMissingYearMonthNumber
    RETURN
        IF ( Result = 1, 0, Result )
)
```

and

```
Consecutive Months On Hold = 
IF (
    T[Status] = "On Hold",
    VAR FirstYear =
        MIN ( T[Year] )
    VAR CurrentYear = T[Year]
    VAR CurrentMonth = T[Month]
    VAR CurrentYearMonthNumber = ( CurrentYear - FirstYear ) * 12 + CurrentMonth
    VAR YearMonths =
        GENERATE (
            SELECTCOLUMNS ( GENERATESERIES ( FirstYear, CurrentYear ), "Year", [Value] ),
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, 12, 1 ),
                "Month", [Value],
                "YearMonthNumber",
                     ( [Year] - FirstYear ) * 12 + [Value]
            )
        )
    VAR CurrentIDAndStatusYearMonths =
        CALCULATETABLE (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                SUMMARIZE ( T, T[Year], T[Month] ),
                "YearMonthNumber",
                     ( T[Year] - FirstYear ) * 12 + T[Month]
            ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( T, T[ID], T[Status] )
        )
    VAR MissingYearMonths =
        EXCEPT ( YearMonths, CurrentIDAndStatusYearMonths )
    VAR FirstMissingYearMonthNumber =
        MAXX (
            FILTER ( MissingYearMonths, [YearMonthNumber] < CurrentYearMonthNumber ),
            [YearMonthNumber]
        )
    VAR Result = CurrentYearMonthNumber - FirstMissingYearMonthNumber
    RETURN
        IF ( Result = 1, 0, Result )
)
```

this is the resulting table put in a table visual

[image: table visual]

Comment: here is the link to my github for the direct download of the sample pbix I used to check this DAX code https://github.com/SergioMurru/shared/raw/main/DatAlessia%20DAX%20or%20M%20count%20for%20consecutive%20months%20for%20every%20ID%20in%20PowerBI/DatAlessia%20DAX%20or%20M%20count%20for%20consecutive%20months%20for%20every%20ID%20in%20PowerBI.pbix